# How to detect whether react app page is running on browser or under Webview2

Tags: reactjs, typescript, wpf, webview2

How to detect whether react app page is running on browser or under Webview2

Hi,

I am working on a react app and I have to show some react page with some content hide if it is rendering in webview2 in a WPF application or full page with full content  if it is running on web.

Do we some straight forward solution to find out so that I can put that check on react js side to show or hide the page content.

I was using below to give a difference but came to know web view2 is using edge only to render the content.

import { browserName, browserVersion } from "react-device-detect";

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to detect `WebView2` from javascript:

```
console.log(!!window.chrome.webview);
```

This will return `true` when running inside `WebView2` (and false when running in browser).

Then you can simply set the style:

```
document.getElementById('myHiddenElement').style.display = "none";
```

**Edit** (from your comment):

What you're seeing is a Typescript error, because `window.chrome` is not standard javascript. You need to add a 'index.d.ts' file to your project with the following content:

```
declare global
{
    interface Window
    {
        chrome: Chrome;
    }

    interface Chrome
    {
        webview: WebView2;
    }

    interface WebView2
    {
    }
}

export { };
```

Now Typescript should 'shut up'.

Comment: Hi Poul, Thanks for your reply. Actually I am using React with type Script and by applying above it gives me below error.                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                       
Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts(2339)

Comment: I had already tried this but still the same issue present .                                                       Property 'chrome' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.ts.                               What I am thinking I can take any property of navigator that is present on web but not coming as console under WPF like const isthisweb = navigator.storage;. I think it will be just a arrangement not solution that should work to differentiate.